# Playback state in JWPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, jwplayer, playback

We are using `MPMoviePlayerController` and using 'playbackState' function we can identify the state (`MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped`, `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying`, `MoviePlaybackStatePaused`, `MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted`, `MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward`, `MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward`).

I am migrating the app to use `JWPlayer`. `JWPlayer` has 4 states - `idle`, `playing`, `paused` and `buffering`.

As I understand, the mapping of the states is like -

- MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying <-> playing
- MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped <-> idle
- MoviePlaybackStatePaused <-> paused
- MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted <-> ?
- MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward <-> ?
- MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward <-> ?

What is the correct mapping?

I can use `JWPlayerDelegate` as well and implement functions like 'onComplete', etc, but at some places I just want to get the current state and take an action.

Comment: You should ask JWPlayer about it , i faced similar issue its code is not available publicly update question accordingly

Comment: What was your work around?